# High revving when I push in the clutch

Tags: troubleshooting, subaru, impreza, outback

So my 05 impreza outback sport is having a high revving issue. It mostly does it when it's been warmed up and it's been getting worse.in between shifting and when I just push in the clutch, I'm at a loss here so if anyone can help that'd be great.

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair!

Answer (score 1):

It'd help if you described the situation a bit more extensively.
What exactly happens and under which circumstances?

If you don't let go off the accelerator at all during shifting, then it's obvious that the engine will start to rev. Some ECU's are programmed so that it's best to completely relieve the accelerator, then clutch and shift, and then apply the accelerator again. The accelerator input is filtered that way. VAG cars are notorious for this, many people find it annoying to drive. I don't know how Subaru does this.

If the engine revs higher than normally when you have released the clutch again and applied the gas, then it may mean the clutch is worn. You have to describe your problem better for us to give a good answer.